# PHP jQuery datatables ajax refresh Not Working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I've looked through many SO posts on this issue, and I cannot seem to find a fix for my problem so I turn to you.

I'm simply making an AJAX call to an external php file to gather the appropriate data (or rows) to refill my table.

The (*insert_new_job.php*) AJAX call performs a MySQL query to insert data into a database. That functionality works just fine. The problem is when I want to refresh the *jobs_table.php* file which queries the database and displays all of the information in rows. 
I'm hoping to refresh the jQuery Datatable to show the newly inserted row.

I receive the error:

> DataTables warning: table id=unit_jobs - Invalid JSON response

HTML:

```
<table class='table datatable stripe hover' id='unit_jobs'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Job Number</th>
        <th>Applications</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Model Number</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Added</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='jobs_table_body'>
      <?php include ("jobs_table.php"); ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dt = $('.datatable').dataTable();


    $('#create_job_btn').click(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'insert_new_job.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {job:jobnum, cust:customer, typ:unit_typ, ae:ae_sel, model:nom},
           success:function(){
               noty({text: 'Job entered into the database successfully', layout: 'topRight', type: 'success'});
               setTimeout(function() {
                   $.noty.closeAll();
               }, 3000);                                
           },
           complete:function(data) {
               $('#jobs_table_body').empty().append(data);
               dt.api().ajax.reload();
           }                            
        });

    } else {}
   });

});
```

jobs_table.php:

```
<?php   
require_once ("config.php");
$res = $db_qms->prepare("SELECT `a`.`ID`, `a`.`JOBNUM`, `a`.`UNIT_TYPE`, `a`.`MODELNUM`, `a`.`DESCRIP`, `a`.`DATE_ADDED`, `b`.`TYP`, `c`.`FIRSTNAME`, `c`.`LASTNAME` FROM `jobs_engineering` `a` INNER JOIN `unit_types` `b` ON `a`.`UNIT_TYPE`=`b`.`ID` INNER JOIN `users` `c` ON `a`.`AEID`=`c`.`USERID` ORDER BY `a`.`DATE_ADDED` DESC");
$res->execute();
while ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['JOBNUM'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . ucwords(strtolower($row['FIRSTNAME'] . " " . $row['LASTNAME'])) . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['TYP'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['MODELNUM'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['DESCRIP'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . date('m/d/Y h:i A',strtotime($row['DATE_ADDED'])) . "</td>";  
    echo "<td><button data-val='" . $row['ID'] . "' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'><span class='fa fa-edit' style='margin-right:0;'></span></button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

UPDATE. THE PROPER AJAX CALL SHOULD BE:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'insert_new_job.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {job:jobnum, cust:customer, typ:unit_typ, ae:ae_sel, model:nom},
    success:function(data){
        noty({text: 'Job entered into the database successfully', layout: 'topRight', type: 'success'});
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.noty.closeAll();
        }, 3000);                               
        $.ajax({
            url: 'jobs_table.php',
            success:function(data){
                $('#jobs_table_body').empty().append(data);
            }
        });
    }                       
    });
```

Comment: What is your exact Problem?

Comment: I cannot get the datatables to refresh to show the newly inserted information

Comment: Whats your insert_new_jop.php

Comment: it inserts data into the database, nothing else. It has nothing to do with my problem

Comment: Does it really Add the Data?  and what does this line do: `dt.api().ajax.reload();`

Comment: "DataTables warning: table id=unit_jobs - Invalid JSON response"

Can you check that "unit_jobs" and id have compatible types?

Comment: @j_s_stack like I stated in the above paragraph. insert_new_job.php works perfectly. It inserts data because I see it in my database and it shows just fine in my table when I refresh the entire page. Time to move on.

Comment: @GratusD. I'm not quite sure what you mean. The error is stating that the table id (unit_jobs) received an invalid JSON response. If you see in my HTML, the id of the table is unit_jobs

Comment: Yeah I can't see from where you recieve the updated  data?

Comment: ok - I understand it better now. It might have something to do with the INNER JOINS. Take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

It maybe that the new addition is not reflected in an inner join. You might have to do a left join.

Comment: @j_s_stack You are 100% correct. I apologize

Comment: Go into the Networks Tap of your F12 Developer Tools and have a look what your AJAX Request Returns. I think its nothing

Comment: i wrote a  tutorial that explains very well how to do this http://refreshmymind.com/datatables-dom-php-ajax-mysql-datasources/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$('.table-xxx').DataTable().ajax.reload()
```